# Why can't I type into popover form?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

this is my edit.js.erb

```
$(function(){
$('#edit_<%=@task.id%>').popover({
html: true, 
placement: 'bottom',
title: 'title',
content: '<%= escape_javascript render 'edit_form' %>'
});
```

});

and this is the html.erb

```
<% @tasks.each do |task| %>
    <ul>
        <li>
          <%= task.description %>
          <%=link_to(edit_task_path(task),"data-toggle"=>"popover", remote:'true') do %> 
            <span id='edit_<%=task.id%>' class= 'form glyphicon glyphicon-pencil'></span>
          <% end %>
        </li>

    </ul>
  <% end %>
```

When the popover opens up and I click the text area, I just end up sending a GET request and my log returns 200 status.

Comment: text field can be blocked, popover can be overlapped by another element. Many reasons. What happens if you execute the code in a normal markup

Comment: it would route me to edit_task_path and I can edit the text in the form.